# fastest way to compare if two ms sql tables are the same

Tags: c#, sql-server, algorithm, linq, comparison

I want to know the fastest way I can compare if two ms sql table have exactly the same content in c#!

This is the rule: If any row has a difference, program abort and report "different". If no difference found, the program will keep going till the end and report a "same"

I currently tried out using sqlDataReader to compare row by row as I go... this method is really really slow. 
Then I used adaptor to fill a dataTable, and use (found from other post in stackoverflow) and this is still pretty slow:

```
var difference = table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
return differences.Any() ? false : true;
```

I am fairly new to c#, dont know too much methods around. Can anyone please suggest me ways I can speed up the comparison. like dataReader or dataTable? LinQ or looping? Thanks all!

Comment: How many records are in your table? A thousand records? A hundred million? How slow is "slow?" Ten seconds? Five hours?

Comment: I'm comparing two 60GB database... its taking 6 hr +... I need it done under an hour or little over

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to add one important detail... the two table im comparing are from different server. And I DO NOT know any detail about the tables, because this tool is meant to be generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you need to load all the data in memory and compare every row with every row which is inefficient.

Try to join using SQL. Since the DB should be optimized for doing joins it will be much faster (provided there are some indexes to help the join).

If you can't do that for some reason, the alternative is to speed it up using hashes. The logic is simple: read table 1, compute the hash of each row (the built-in hash functions should work just fine), store them in a set (or put them in an array and sort them), then do the same to table 2 and compare the output.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion to do it via SQL Server is a good one, and probably will be the fastest if you can do it. The article at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/ gives some suggestions, although I don't know if any of those do field-by-field comparisons. The [tablediff](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1073/sql-server-tablediff-command-line-utility/) command they reference looks particularly interesting.

At minimum, you should give one or more of those a try, just to get an idea on how fast you can do it.

You can do a record-by-record search easily enough using [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx), which gives optimized forward-only, read-only access to results. The basic idea is:

```
var query1 = "Select * from table1 order by recordId";
var connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection1);
var reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

var query2 = "Select * from table2 order by recordId";
var connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection2);
var reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

var gotRow1 = reader1.Read();
var gotRow2 = reader2.Read();

while (gotRow1 && gotRow2)
{
    bool isSame = true;
    for each field
        if (compare(field1, field2) != true)
        {
            isSame = false;
            break;
        }
    if (isSame)
    {
        gotRow1 = reader1.Read();
        gotRow2 = reader2.Read();
    }
}

if (gotRow1 || gotRow2)
{
    // there are differences
}
```

That code isn't optimized and doesn't do any error handling, and in fact won't compile because I didn't write the field comparison code. But it should give you the idea of what needs to happen. I honestly don't know if it'll be any faster than what you already have, but it might be worth a try. You could put a counter in there and output after every 1,000 rows or something so you know how fast it's going.

Your biggest problem, though, is that the database must sort to satisfy the `order by`, which is required to make sure you're comparing records with the same IDs. And if there's a large number of records (you didn't say how many records there are), that's going to take considerable time.

Note also that if you're really transferring 60 GB of data for each table, just data transmission time on a 1 GB network will be *at best* 10 minutes per table. More likely longer than that, especially if there is other stuff happening on your network.

You really are much better off running this on the server, if you can.